# Fetching data from Django models related via foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model in Django that looks like this (I've simplified the tables & skipped the irrelevant fields. I can't change the tables/relations):

```
Class Attachment(models.Model): 
    name    = models.CharField()

Class Email(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField()
    from    = models.ForeignKey(User)
    attach  = models.ForeignKey(Attachment)

Class User(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField()
```

In my view, I want to find all the `Users` that have sent this attachment. So, first I fetch all the emails that contain the this attachment

```
my_attachment = Attachment.objects.get(name='Picture1.jpg')
email_set     = my_attachment.email_set.all()
```

What's an **efficient** way to fetch all the users that are listed in the `from` field of emails in `email_set` i.e. without looping through email_set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easy and **efficient** way:

```
users = ( User
          .objects
          .filter( email__attachment__name = 'Picture1.jpg' )
          .distinct()
        )
```

Remember to create needed indexes to your database tables.

Comment: User.objects.filter surely?

Comment: Works & looks simple in Django 

but it translates to a scary sql statement : SELECT `user`.`id`, `user`.`name` FROM `user` INNER JOIN `email` ON ( `user`.`id` = `email`.`user_id` ) INNER JOIN `attachment` ON ( `email`.`attach_id` = `attachment`.`id` ) WHERE `attachment`.`name` = %Picture1.jpg%

Comment: I see a cleaned and elegant sql sentence. Where is the issue? All is right!